# GeoSpacial Mongodb query using LinearRings

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to fetch recently sold homes within a donut that has a 1609 sqm thick outter ring and a 464 sqm innter circle. See illustration below. I'm not able to find good examples on how to do this. The closest I could find is within the mongodb documenation but it uses a triangle https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/geojson/#polygons-with-multiple-rings

[image: search radius]

Comment: How about using [`"$near"` or `"$nearSphere"` with `"$minDistance"` and `"$maxDistance"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/minDistance/#use-with--near "Link to MongoDB docs -->")?

Comment: This looks promising! I'll give this a try